# foreach loop gives error CategoryInfo : InvalidData: (:) [Get-ADUser], ParameterBindingValidationException

Tags: powershell, foreach, active-directory

I am trying to run a cmdlet on each element of a list. but i am getting the error `ObjectNotFound: (*@{samAccountName=my_ad_username}*:ADUser) [Get-ADUser], ADIdentityNotFoundException` for each element of my list.

Bellow is cmdlet

```
$users = Get-ADUser -Filter "*" -SearchBase "OU=Europe,DC=myDC,DC=com" | select samAccountName

$fr_all_grp_assigned_to_different_users = Foreach ($user in $users){ 
        #Get-AdUser $user
    }
```

Result

```
> Get-ADUser : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The
> Identity property on the argument is null or empty. At line:6 char:20
> +         Get-aduser $user
> +                    ~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-ADUser], ParameterBindingValidationException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser
> Get-ADUser : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The
> Identity property on the argument is null or empty. At line:6 char:20
> +         Get-aduser $user
```

Line 6 refers to `#Get-AdUser $user`

Can anyone help ?

Comment: Use `get-aduser $user.samaccountname`

Comment: Perfect, it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside of your loop, you need to provide the `SamAccountName` value to the `-Identity` parameter of `Get-ADUser`.

```
Get-ADUser -Identity $user.SamAccountName
```

---

**Explanation:**

You can execute `Get-ADUser` by providing values manually to parameters or piping objects into the command and let advanced parameter assignment dynamically map values to parameters. Some parameters are positional in that you don't need to specify the parameter name when running the command with a value(s). These features/concepts exists across most PowerShell commands.

In the case of `Get-ADUser Value`, `Value` is automatically mapped to parameter `-Identity`. `-Identity` expects one of the following values:

> - A distinguished name
> - A GUID (objectGUID)
> - A security identifier (objectSid)
> - A SAM account name (sAMAccountName)

`Get-ADUser` has a convenient feature where if you pass it a `Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser` object type (returned from a directory server) through a pipe or to the `-Identity` parameter, it will automatically perform a search based on the provided values. If you provide it any other object type, it will not automatically select property values to pass to `-Identity`. Piping to `Select SamAccountName` returns a `PSCustomObject` rather than an `ADUser` object and then you lose your convenience.

Once you are dealing with objects that are not `ADUser`, you must provide `-Identity` with the actual value you want to query. In your case, that leaves you with two options.

**Option 1: Select only SamAccountName values in your initial query**

With this option, you can make use of the `-ExpandProperty` or `-Expand` parameter of `Select-Object` to return only the values of the target property.

```
$users = Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Europe,DC=myDC,DC=com" |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty SamAccountName
$fr_all_grp_assigned_to_different_users = Foreach ($user in $users) {
    Get-ADUser $user
}
```

**Option 2: Use Member Access operator (`.`) to directly access the SamAccountName value**

With this option you can use the syntax `object.Property` to retrieve the `Property` value.

```
# Using the singular object.Property ($user.SamAccountName)
$users = Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Europe,DC=myDC,DC=com" |
    Select-Object SamAccountName
$fr_all_grp_assigned_to_different_users = Foreach ($user in $users) {
    Get-ADUser $user.SamAccountName
}
```

Starting with PowerShell v3, you can use the same syntax on a collection to return a collection of values (`collection.Property`).

```
# Using collection.Property ($users.SamAccountName)
# $user contains only a SamAccountName value here
$users = Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Europe,DC=myDC,DC=com" |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty SamAccountName
$fr_all_grp_assigned_to_different_users = Foreach ($user in $users.SamAccountName) {
    Get-ADUser $user
}
```